# mvc jquery modal popup dialog ui-widget-overlay issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, popup

I am using Blueprint and jQuery UI/jQuery 1.11.1 with .Net MVC in the project I am working on.

```
<div id="loading_dialog" class="hide">
    <div class="span-5 prepend-4 prepend-top">
        <img id="progressIndicator" src="@Url.Content("~/loading-image-url-here")" alt="Progress Indicator" />
    </div>
    <span class="span-2 prepend-4 small">&nbsp;&nbsp;Loading...</span>
</div>
```

That's the code for the modal dialog which I have in a partial view on my layout page. On submission of a form, I have this code to display the popup:

```
$('.formSubmit').submit(function () {
    $('body, html').animate({ scrollTop: $('html') });
    $("#loading_dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        height: 150,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        position: { my: "center top+100", at: 'top+150', of: ".formSubmit" },
        closeOnEscape: false,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
        }
    });
    $('.ui-dialog').wrap('<div class="jquery_elem" />');
    $('.ui-widget-overlay').wrap('<div class="jquery_elem" />');
});
```

I need to wrap the div that the jQuery adds to the bottom of the page with class="jquery_elem" because I elected to have the jQuery UI scoped to this selector. I am using the following CSS for the overlay:

```
.ui-widget-overlay {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    background: url("Images/FotoFlexer_Photo.png") repeat;
}   

.ui-dialog {
    z-index: 999 !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    top: 150px !important;    
}
```

However when I click the submit button the dialog appears without the overlay. I have another modal for errors that displays with the overlay, can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

Found out the cause of this today, it was the z-index for the overlay causing the image to not show up. I added a z-index to the .ui-widget-overlay class in line 876 of jquery-ui.css to fix things.